# Struts2 configuration failed - import failed

Tags: struts2, annotations

While doing Struts with annotations i have this problem. 
`The import org.apache.struts2.config.Result cannot be resolved`
I can't find which library it belongs to so that i can download it.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use annotations for declarative architecture in your Struts2 web application, you should import struts2-convention-plugin-xxx.jar which contains all the annotations available.